# No enclosing instance of type savings is accessible in java

Tags: java, oop

im just getting message like "No enclosing instance of type savings is accessible." starting in line 17. I don't know what kind of instance that the IDE means. I'm learning java for 2 weeks now.

```
public class savings {
class MyInfo{
    String name;
    int balance;
}
class MyParent{
    String name;
    int balance;
}
class Mysister{
    String name;
    int balance;
}
public class Mainsimulationsavings {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    MyInfo me = new MyInfo();
    me.name ="gaga";
    me.balance =1000000;
    
    MyParent parent = new MyParent();
    parent.name ="Abdul";
    parent.balance =20000000;
    
    Mysister sis = new Mysister();
    sis.name ="Ifdah";
    sis.balance =500000 ;
    
    System.out.printf("|%-5s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n", "No", "No.ID", "balance", "name");
    System.out.printf("|%-5s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n", "--", "----", "-----", "----");
    System.out.printf("|%-5s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n", "1", "12345", "Rp."+me.balance,me.name);
    System.out.printf("|%-5s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n", "2", "54321", "Rp."+parent.balance,parent.name);
    System.out.printf("|%-5s|%-10s|%-10s|%-10s|\n", "3", "67890", "Rp."+sis.balance,sis.name);
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Sticking classes in classes makes 'instance classes' which you don't want, usually. They have an extra invisible field of their outer type: You can't make new instances of e.g. `Mysister` here without also having an instance of `savings` available, which you don't. This is all very confusing so you never want to do this until you're much more advanced in java (and even then, I generally avoid it, saving a few characters at the cost of confusing code is rarely a good tradeoff).

Either don't stick classes in classes, or remember to *always* mark classes-in-classes as `static`. Such as `static class MyParent {`.

Comment: ok, thanks sir, that was great advice.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785049/642706) is correct.

The likely solution is to move those related classes to *outside* the `Savings` class.

Also, given your naming, you seem to be confusing the idea of classes with instances. There is no need for `MyInfo` and `MyParent` and `MySister`. The state and behavior of those are all the same. The only difference is their relationship to you. Instead, using a single class `Person`. And, either add a `relationship` member field to the class, or imply the relationship through the naming of instance variables. See code below.

Tip: Define your classes more briefly as a record if their main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably.

By the way, watch your naming. Java naming conventions start a class name with an uppercase letter. So `Savings`, not `savings`.

```java
record Person ( String name , int balance ) {}
```

Another tip: A record can be declared locally, within a method. Or declare by nesting in a class. Or declare separately, in its own `.java` file.

Yet another tip: You can use a LOW LINE (underscore) character to arbitrarily group the digits of a numeric literal.

In your `main` method, or other such code, instantiate.

```java
Person me = new Person( "Gaga" , 1_000_000 ) ;
Person parent = new Person( "Abdul" , 20_000_000 ) ;
Person sister = new Person( "Ifdah" , 500_000 ) ;
```

Make a list and loop, to report.

```java
List<Person> persons = List.of( me , parent , sister ) ;
for( Person person : persons ) 
{
    System.out.println( "Name: " + person.name() … ) ;
}
```